# Shoutbox Multiple Windows/tabs not displaying all shouts

Tags: php, jquery

I have a problem with my Shoutbox, when you have say 2 tabs open on your Web Browser and you are sending / receiving messages.. 
This is an issue in all Browsers.

Problem: It shares the messages between both tabs so you see some shouts in one tab and some in the other.. Never all of them in either of both tabs..

The Shoutbox is coded in PHP MySQL and Jquery.. Uses a refresh.txt file to check for new shouts then get new the if any shouts.

I would like to either have it so the 2nd tab you open displays a message saying you already have the shoutbox open in another window shouts will be displayed in the 1st window open.... Or maybe just display everything in both.. 1st option would be the best!

How would I tackle this?

I don't have any source code to show you as I don't know where to start with this.
Any help would be a amazing its something that I have been trying to work out for a while.